# Unable to find the latitude and longitude

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager, android-location, locationlistener

I wrote code for finding the latitude and longitude of a place and it works well in my PC using Eclipse but it does not work on my Android phone.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    protected Button retrieveLocationButton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        retrieveLocationButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.retrieve_location_button);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1,
                1000, new MyLocationListener());
        retrieveLocationButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showCurrentLocation();
            }
        });
    }

    protected void showCurrentLocation() {
        Location location = locationManager
                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (location != null) {
            String message = String.format(
                    "Current Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
                    location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude());
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    }

    private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            String message = String.format(
                    "New Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
                    location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude());
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Provider status changed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "Provider disabled by the user. GPS turned off",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "Provider enabled by the user. GPS turned on",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you give us a little more to go on? Code etc.

Comment: Whenever you are mentioning you wrote some code let us know what you have written by posting some related piece of code.

Comment: if you are using device, than make sure your device's GPS is on as well as network location, because sometimes it takes time to get GPS, untile that it will return 0.0 only.

Comment: @AdeelPervaiz ya I turned on the GPS. How to find whether network location is enabled or disabled?

Comment: See this Answer With proper solution 
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720785/android-when-stop-gps-listener-force-close/11721290#comment15552695_11721290][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720785/android-when-stop-gps-listener-force-close/11721290#comment15552695_11721290

Comment: Is this because of the Android device which I use? My version is 2.3.3.. Will it work only in 4.0.3 ??

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you have given all the required permissions in AndroidManifest file to access gps...

```
android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
android.permission.INTERNET
```

See this link : https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/using-the-gps

Comment: I think my code is similar to that code.. It works well in my PC but not in my android phone